# Vuetify navigation overlay can not be dismissed with .click() in TestCafe

Tags: automated-tests, vuetify.js, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm using TestCafe to test a Vue app that uses a Vuetify navigation drawer. When the drawer is open, it creates a grey overlay on top of the rest of the app. I should be able to click on that overlay to close the drawer. This is not working; the drawer remains open and the overlay does not go away.

However, if I add a `.debug()`, unlock the page and clicking manually, the overlay and drawer are dismissed as expected and the rest of the test can proceed.

The quick little test below demonstrates the problem. It uses [the example in Vuetify's docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers#temporary) as the fixture, opens the drawer, clicks the overlay, and expects the overlay to no longer exist. This will fail because the overlay is still visible after the click.

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Vuetify navigation drawer`
    .page `https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers`

test('is closed when clicking the overlay', async t => {
    await t
        .click('a[href="#temporary"] + div + div div.v-sheet button')
        .click('div.v-overlay')
        //.debug(); // unlock & manual click on overlay will result in a pass
        .expect(Selector('div.v-overlay').exists).eql(false);
});
```

[This thread](https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/t/api-click-on-a-div-element-with-an-onclick-handler-supported/110) sounded promising but the resulting bug was fixed 2 years ago and the suggested workaround of adding a `.hover()` does not work.

I've tried both Firefox 66 and Chrome 72, on MacOS 10.14, with testcafe v1.1.0.

Any idea why clicking the overlay is not working and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: If I am not wrong, it looks like TestCafe does not handle correctly this kind of click event. May be you could open an issue on TestCafe

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the issue is that Vuetify uses some checks of the [event.isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) property.

Since TestCafe uses the dispatchEvent method internally, the event.isTrusted property returns false, while Vuetify expects to get true.

At this moment I can only recommend you remove the overlay by using the [ClientFunctions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/) mechanism.

We have plans to modify our event processing mechanism. Please follow our progress with the [#2543 issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2543).